# Оборот "по сравнению"

Tags: пунктуация

Выделяется ли запятыми оборот "по сравнению"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, выделяется как обстоятельственный оборот.
"Собака, по сравнению с кошкой, как правило, намного крупнее"

Answer (score 1):

Позволю себе возразить: академические грамматики говорят, что обособление оборотов с предлогом *по сравнению с* факультативно. В примере Kagami обособление как раз нежелательно: предложение получается перегруженным знаками препинания. Рекомендуемая пунктуация: *Собака по сравнению с кошкой, как правило, намного крупнее.*

Answer (score 0):

Совершенно согласна с Ларис де Ниша. Выделение не требуется.

Comment: Парис, с вашего позволения. К тому же имя склоняется. :)